# ExtJs 6.7.0- treePanel with rowWidget misaligned when using locked column

Tags: extjs, treegrid, locked, treepanel

I have an **Ext.tree.Panel** with a *rowWidget* using **Ext.grid.Panel**, when I lock the first column of **Ext.tree.Panel** the *rowWidget* expansion doesn't expand the locked column all the way.

I understand that when I lock a column the tree/grid split into 2 synced grids, one for the locked columns and another with the rest. The rowWidget expansion occurs only on the unlocked section.

I would like to know if there's a way to properly sync the expansion of both grids.

[image: Misalignment shown]

I built a fiddle reproducing the situation from image above. If line 41 (*locked: true*) is removed, the locking on column, it works just fine.

[TREEPANEL_LOCKED_ROWWIDGET](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3kf7)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could force a refresh on the locked grid when the row widget is expanded;

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3kh1)